# Twiiter API failed to get followers and following details

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I want to get the twitter followers and following person details. i know that not present any direct mechanism to get all the detail. so i first get the id's of all friends. i used this API to get the id's.

```
NSURL * requestAPI =[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json"];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:twitterAccount.username, @"screen_name", nil]; // Fo rthis Api you need to pass these parmeter is necessary
```

and pass this parameter and get the list of id's.

and using that ids i want to get the all details about friends. so i tried this API

```
 NSURL * requestAPIForNames =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=%@",result]];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                     [parameters1 setObject:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" forKey:@"oauth_consumer_key"];

                     [parameters1 setObject:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" forKey:@"oauth_consumer_secret"];
```

i have pass the all id's to this API. and want to get the details of followers. but not sucess.
i get the following issue.

```
{
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 32;
            message = "Could not authenticate you";
        }
    );
}
```

why this happening can anyone help me to do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: @rmaddy can u help me to solve this one

Comment: did u find the solution..if yes then then please tell me how u resolve this. I am also suffering from this problem and i m completely stuck over here..